# Set "ouf of paper" status for print job from the driver (programmatically)

Tags: printing, driver, jobs, printers

My goal is to implement functionality in the driver which allows to define is it possible print new page. This code asks printer if there's enough paper to print current page and if not then it should set "out of paper" status (like it works for HP printer).[image]

For doing this I use DDI hooks (for Start Page). What I did here is:

```
        LPJOB_INFO_1    pJobInfo    = NULL;
    GetJob(hPrinter, pOemPDEV->JobId, 1, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded);

    if ( GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
        return FALSE;

    pJobInfo = (LPJOB_INFO_1) AllocSplMem(dwNeeded);

    if (!pJobInfo)
        return FALSE;

    BOOL getJobRes = GetJob(hPrinter, pOemPDEV->JobId, 1, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, dwNeeded, &dwNeeded);
    if (!getJobRes)
        return FALSE;

    wsprintf(string, L"pJobInfo->Status %d", pJobInfo->Status);
    VERBOSE(string);

    pJobInfo->Status |= JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT;    

    BOOL a = SetJob(hPrinter, pOemPDEV->JobId, 1, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, JOB_CONTROL_PAUSE);
```

In result I have:

- SetJob returns FALSE and error is 5 (Access denied)
- status changed to "Paused", however Out-Of-Paper did not appear:
  [image]

The question is how to set JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, sorry. I follow the tag [print-spooler-api](/questions/tagged/print-spooler-api). Anyway, you probably solved this months ago, but you might get Access Denied if you don't set Position to JOB_POSITION_UNSPECIFIED.